# Renumbering the remaining records after deleting one of them

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, sorting

I have a database in SQL server using Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC. I have a column named "S No." representing serial numbers. Now when I delete a record from database, obviously the "S No." skips that records serial number. I want to re number the "S No." column using my controller. Is there any algorithm so that i can easily renumber them again?

Here is the code of AddFeature() method where i am numbering the "S No." column.

```
  public ActionResult AddFeature(Models.SoftwareFeatureList s)
    {
        ViewBag.Username = uname;
        ViewBag.UserType = utype;
        try
        {
            c = new DatabaseZTBLEntities();
            s.FormId = formid;
            int identity = c.SoftwareFeatureLists.Where(u=>u.FormId.Equals(formid)).Count() +1;
            s.S_No_ = identity;
            c.SoftwareFeatureLists.Add(s);

            c.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = e.Message;
            return View("error");
        }
        finally
        {
            c.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
        return Redirect("FeaturesListPage");
    }
```

Comment: Why using `Count()`? Can't you just use `Max() +1` and do not worry about renumbering?

Comment: If you have a where condition and count+1, it can not reset the serial number. Does the SoftwareFeatureList parameter contains the list which needs the SNO to be reset?

Comment: Why do you need a Serial no column? Is there a special requirement for it?

Comment: if a serial number is subject to change due to something being removed, why would you have one in the first place?

Comment: Pablo, actually count() is used to get the number of records for the specific account/id/form. Max()+1 shall also be suitable.
Najiullah, yes it is for showing a sequence of items contained in a specific account/object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Do not keep S_no as a column in database, but generate its value on the fly when returning the records on Read operation.
2. If you still want to keep S_no in the database, you need to update your database directly (using triggers) whenever any delete happens.

   row_number() over(partition by formId order by formId)

Comment: Keeping the Value on the fly is a great idea. I should try implementing it.